# Is the weak limit of a sequence of translation-invariant measures itself translation-invariant?

Tags: measure-theory

> > Let $(X,\mathcal{B})$ be a measure space and $(\mu_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of translation-invariant measures on it that converges weakly to the measure $\nu$ on $(X,\mathcal{B})$. Is then $\nu$ translation-invariant, too?

Weak limit means that for all $f\in C_b(X)$ it is
$$
\lim_n\int_Xf\, d\mu_n=\int_Xf\, d\nu
$$
and translation-invariance for each $\mu_n,n\in\mathbb{N}$, means that
$$
\mu_n(T^{-1}(B))=\mu(B)
$$
for a translation $T\colon X\to X$ and $B\in\mathcal{B}$.

But I do not see exactly if then
$$
\nu(T^{-1}(B))=\nu(B).
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the characteristic function $f = \chi_A$ for some $A\in\mathcal B$ and the same for $\chi_{T^{-1}A}$. Then
$$\nu(T^{-1}A) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \mu_n (T^{-1}A) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \mu_n(A) = \nu(A)$$
Because $\nu(A) = \int_X \chi_A \mathrm d\nu$ for any measure.

Comment: Ah, great, thank you very much.

Comment: But $f = \chi_{A}$ is not continuous, right?